# when I try to run my pyqt5 app the window's sizes changing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer

I've designed an app ui using QT designer and convert it to .py file but when ever I try to run the app with python the window's size does not show as in the QT designer and some texts are cut.

I've changed my python version and didn't work.

I also tried Sublime instead of pycharm and faced the same issue. I've tried my code in another computer and  works correctly. Any Tip!

**q64686336_main.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType
import os
from os import path


ui, _ = loadUiType(path.join(path.dirname(__file__),"q64686336.ui"))


class MainApp(QMainWindow, ui):
    def __init__(self , parent=None):
        super(MainApp , self).__init__(parent)
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
 

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**q64686336.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>496</width>
    <height>246</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">
QWidget {
    background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
    color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
    border-color: rgb(58, 58, 58);
}

QPlainTextEdit {
    background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
    color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
    selection-background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    selection-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

QTabWidget::pane {
        border-top: 1px solid #000000;
}

QTabBar::tab {
    background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-style: outset;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-right-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.4, y1:0.5, x2:0.6, y2:0.5, stop:0 rgba(115, 115, 115, 255), stop:1 rgba(62, 62, 62, 255));
    border-left-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.6, y1:0.5, x2:0.4, y2:0.5, stop:0 rgba(115, 115, 115, 255), stop:1 rgba(62, 62, 62, 255));
  border-bottom-color: rgb(58, 58, 58);
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    padding: 4px;
}

QTabBar::tab:selected, QTabBar::tab:hover {
   color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
   background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
   border-color:rgb(42, 42, 42);
   margin-left: 0px;
   margin-right: 0px;
   border-bottom-right-radius:4px;
   border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
}

QTabBar::tab:last:selected {
  background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-color:rgb(42, 42, 42);
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
}

QTabBar::tab:!selected {
   margin-bottom: 4px;
   border-bottom-right-radius:4px;
   border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
}

QPushButton{
    border-style: outset;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-top-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.5, y1:0.6, x2:0.5, y2:0.4, stop:0 rgba(115, 115, 115, 255), stop:1 rgba(62, 62, 62, 255));
    border-right-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.4, y1:0.5, x2:0.6, y2:0.5, stop:0 rgba(115, 115, 115, 255), stop:1 rgba(62, 62, 62, 255));
    border-left-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.6, y1:0.5, x2:0.4, y2:0.5, stop:0 rgba(115, 115, 115, 255), stop:1 rgba(62, 62, 62, 255));
    border-bottom-color: rgb(58, 58, 58);
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding: 6px;
    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.5, y1:1, x2:0.5, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(77, 77, 77, 255), stop:1 rgba(97, 97, 97, 255));
}

QPushButton:hover{
    border-style: outset;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-top-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.5, y1:0.6, x2:0.5, y2:0.4, stop:0 rgba(180, 180, 180, 255), stop:1 rgba(110, 110, 110, 255));
    border-right-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.4, y1:0.5, x2:0.6, y2:0.5, stop:0 rgba(180, 180, 180, 255), stop:1 rgba(110, 110, 110, 255));
    border-left-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.6, y1:0.5, x2:0.4, y2:0.5, stop:0 rgba(180, 180, 180, 255), stop:1 rgba(110, 110, 110, 255));
    border-bottom-color: rgb(115, 115, 115);
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding: 6px;
    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.5, y1:1, x2:0.5, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(107, 107, 107, 255), stop:1 rgba(157, 157, 157, 255));
}

QPushButton:pressed{
    border-style: outset;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-top-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.5, y1:0.6, x2:0.5, y2:0.4, stop:0 rgba(62, 62, 62, 255), stop:1 rgba(22, 22, 22, 255));
    border-right-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.4, y1:0.5, x2:0.6, y2:0.5, stop:0 rgba(115, 115, 115, 255), stop:1 rgba(62, 62, 62, 255));
    border-left-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.6, y1:0.5, x2:0.4, y2:0.5, stop:0 rgba(115, 115, 115, 255), stop:1 rgba(62, 62, 62, 255));
    border-bottom-color: rgb(58, 58, 58);
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding: 6px;
    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.5, y1:1, x2:0.5, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(77, 77, 77, 255), stop:1 rgba(97, 97, 97, 255));
}

QPushButton:disabled{
    border-style: outset;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-top-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.5, y1:0.6, x2:0.5, y2:0.4, stop:0 rgba(115, 115, 115, 255), stop:1 rgba(62, 62, 62, 255));
    border-right-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.4, y1:0.5, x2:0.6, y2:0.5, stop:0 rgba(115, 115, 115, 255), stop:1 rgba(62, 62, 62, 255));
    border-left-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.6, y1:0.5, x2:0.4, y2:0.5, stop:0 rgba(115, 115, 115, 255), stop:1 rgba(62, 62, 62, 255));
    border-bottom-color: rgb(58, 58, 58);
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    padding: 6px;
    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.5, y1:1, x2:0.5, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(57, 57, 57, 255), stop:1 rgba(77, 77, 77, 255));
}

QLineEdit {
    border-width: 1px; border-radius: 4px;
    border-color: rgb(58, 58, 58);
    border-style: inset;
    padding: 0 8px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background:rgb(101, 101, 101);
    selection-background-color: rgb(187, 187, 187);
    selection-color: rgb(60, 63, 65);
}

QProgressBar {
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-width: 1px; 
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-color: rgb(58, 58, 58);
    border-style: inset;
}

QProgressBar::chunk {
    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.5, y1:0.7, x2:0.5, y2:0.3, stop:0 rgb(255 , 0 , 0), stop:1 rgb(255 , 0 , 0));
    border-radius: 10px;
}

QMenuBar {
    background:rgb(0, 0, 0);
    color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

QMenuBar::item {
    spacing: 3px; 
    padding: 1px 4px;
    background: transparent;
}

QMenuBar::item:selected { 
    background:rgb(115, 115, 115);
}

QMenu {
    border-width: 2px; 
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    border-style: outset;
}

QMenu::item {
    spacing: 3px; 
    padding: 3px 15px;
}

QMenu::item:selected {
    spacing: 3px; 
    padding: 3px 15px;
    background:rgb(115, 115, 115);
    color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-width: 1px; 
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-color: rgb(58, 58, 58);
    border-style: inset;
}</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>481</width>
      <height>221</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="currentIndex">
     <number>1</number>
    </property>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_3">
     <attribute name="title">
      <string>Tab 1</string>
     </attribute>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>20</x>
        <y>20</y>
        <width>47</width>
        <height>21</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>URL </string>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>20</x>
        <y>63</y>
        <width>47</width>
        <height>21</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Location</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>340</x>
        <y>60</y>
        <width>71</width>
        <height>25</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Browse</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>90</x>
        <y>20</y>
        <width>321</width>
        <height>25</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QProgressBar" name="progressBar">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>103</x>
        <y>100</y>
        <width>291</width>
        <height>25</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="value">
       <number>24</number>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_2">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>90</x>
        <y>60</y>
        <width>251</width>
        <height>25</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>146</x>
        <y>140</y>
        <width>211</width>
        <height>25</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Download</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_2">
     <attribute name="title">
      <string>Tab 2</string>
     </attribute>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>20</x>
        <y>63</y>
        <width>47</width>
        <height>21</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Location</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QProgressBar" name="progressBar_2">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>103</x>
        <y>100</y>
        <width>291</width>
        <height>25</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="value">
       <number>24</number>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>20</x>
        <y>20</y>
        <width>47</width>
        <height>21</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>URL </string>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_3">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>146</x>
        <y>140</y>
        <width>211</width>
        <height>25</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Download</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_3">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>90</x>
        <y>20</y>
        <width>321</width>
        <height>25</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_4">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>90</x>
        <y>60</y>
        <width>251</width>
        <height>25</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_4">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>340</x>
        <y>60</y>
        <width>71</width>
        <height>25</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Browse</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </widget>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>496</width>
     <height>19</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[click here to see how it appears on the preview mode (right side) and how it apears when I run the script (left side)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrO7k.png)

[image]

Comment: Please publish your module `.ui`

Comment: I've uploaded both .py and .ui files on github . you can access it through this link:   https://github.com/Ayman-almaafi/Demo_1

Comment: @AymanAlmaafi The MRE must be in your post because if the links you provide break then your post is useless.

Comment: i ran your application and `.ui` in `Qt Designer`, window sizes are the same. My OS is Windows.

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks for the advise

Comment: @S.Nick I also tried it in another computer and the sizes are the same. I think the issue is in the OS settings but I don't know it.

Comment: What will you get if you install `app.setStyle ("fusion")` after the line `app = QApplication (sys.argv)` ?

Comment: @S.Nick still the same issue

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: if you execute: `pyuic5 q64686336.ui -o q64686336.py -x` 
and then `python q64686336.py` ?

Comment: @musicamante I've added a screenshot at the end of the post

Comment: @S.Nick I've tried to do that and returning the same result

Comment: In my experience, it's not that uncommon for the Qt Designer preview to look a little different than the runtime window. Your UI has no layouts. I would strongly suggest you learn how to use layouts. They are very powerful and will help you make your app look how you want during runtime.

Comment: @AymanAlmaafi it seems to me a high dpi issue. Try adding `os.environ["QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1"` and `QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)` *before* creating the app instance. Besides that, as bfris correctly points out, you should use [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html) as fixed geometries is discouraged for lots of reasons (including this scenario).

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your code:

```
import os

class UI(QMainWindow):

    os.environ["QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).